# Carregar HTML na Div via Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, div

Gostaria de pegar a resposta do ajax, e carregar na div...

Se eu der o load na div, passando o url funciona 100%

```
var detalhamentoDiv = $("#detalhamentoDiv");
detalhamentoDiv.load('/Exemplo/Controller/Teste');
$('#detalhamentoDiv').modal('show')
```

Mas o problema que quero carregar a div com o response do ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Exemplo/Controller/ConfirmarDados",
    type: "post",
    data: postForm, //dados
    success: function (response) {
        var detalhamentoDiv = $("#detalhamentoDiv");
        //como carregar a div com a response??
        //detalhamentoDiv.??
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Código C#

```
 public ActionResult ConfirmarDados()
 {
    var model = ...;
    return PartialView("_ModalDialog", model)
 }
```

Obrigado..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
...
success: function (response) {
    $("#detalhamentoDiv").html(response);
}
...
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!!